# x-coordinate modulo 2 == 1.0 needs different color

Tags: glsl, shader

I need to write a shader where the color of the pixel are black when the following equation is true:

(x-coordinate of pixel) mod 2 == 1

If it is false, the pixel should be white. Therefore I searched the web but it did not work.

More information:
I've an OpenGL scene with 800 x 600 resolution and the teapot in it. The teapot is red. Now I need to create that zebra look.
Here is some code I've wrote, but it didn'T work:

FragmentShader:

```
void main(){
    if (mod(gl_FragCoord[0].x * 800.0 , 2.0) == 0){

        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);

    }else{
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    }
}
```

VertexShader:

```
void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    gl_TexCoord[0]  =   gl_MultiTexCoord0;
}
```

As far as I know, gl_FragCood.x is in range(0,1) therefore I need to multiply with width.

Comment: You have an implicit type cast in your code: `mod` returns a float value which is compared to an integer. This might be the problem! Try an explicit type cast, e.g.: `if( mod( int(gl_FragCoord[0].x * 800.0), 2) == 0) {`

Comment: Wasn't the problem... But now the warning disapeared - Thanks for that

Comment: **emackeys** answer is of course correct - shame on me for not noticing this immediately! Should I remove my previous (misleading) comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting you mention the need to multiply with the width, have you tried without the `* 800.0` in there?  The range of `gl_FragCoord` is such that the distance between adjacent pixels is 1.0, for example `[0.0, 800.0]` or possibly `[0.5, 800.5]`.

Remove the width multiplication and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing directly to 0, try doing a test against 1.0, e.g.

```
void main(){
    if (mod(gl_FragCoord[0].x , 2.0) >= 1.0){

        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);

    }else{
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    }
}
```

That'll avoid precision errors and the cost of rounding.

As `emackey` points out, `gl_FragCoord` is specified in window coordinates, which:

> ... result from scaling and translating Normalized
>   Device Coordinates by the viewport. The parameters to glViewport() and
>   glDepthRange() control this transformation. With the viewport, you can
>   map the Normalized Device Coordinate cube to any location in your
>   window and depth buffer.

So you also don't actually want to multiply by 800 — the incoming coordinates are already in pixels.